# Отсутствует перевод фразы уведомления при попытке отслеживать пост, когда вы заблокированны

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, блокировка, отслеживание-сообщений

Будучи заблокированным, при попытке нажатии на кнопку "Отслеживать", появляется такое сообщение:

[image: Suspended users cannot follow or unfollow posts]

> Suspended users cannot follow or unfollow posts.

У меня получился какой-то такой перевод:

> Отстранённые пользователи не могут отслеживать или прекратить отслеживание постов.

Меня немного смущает слово "отстранённые" и фраза "прекратить отслеживание". Наместо "отстранённые" могло бы подойти слово "заблокированные", что как по мне более удачно, хоть и не соответствует слову "suspended". Может вы сможете подобрать более удачное предложение? Или вы считаете что текущее подходит?

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если сразу в traducir предложение полетело.

Comment: Угу. Если принимаете ответ, надо сразу предлагать в traducir, иначе тема повиснет несделанной.

Comment: Ясненько, буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В отношении пользователя у нас используется термин "участник".

Смысл хорошего перевода в том, чтобы он был понятен пользователю, итого получается:

> Заблокированные участники не могут начать или прекратить отслеживание постов.

На гениальность не претендую, само собой.

Внёс в Traducir https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17951

Comment: Да, совсем забыл про "участник"‘а. Ну на данный момент, считаю ваш вариант перевода лучшим.

Comment: [То же самое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12627/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1#comment54652_12627) предлагаю.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ внес, надеюсь все правильно сделал

Comment: Немного подправил и утвердил. Ждём новых сборок. Текущая 2023.4.21.43403

Comment: @aepot возможно, стоит повесить [статус-завершено]?

Comment: @Зонтик насколько мне известно, эти статусы используются только с меткой "поддержка".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ подскажи по предложению выше, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какому именно??

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну не твоему же :) про метку-статус.

Comment: [Недавно писал про это.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12634/176217) cc @Зонтик

Comment: @aepot наоборот, только с меткой [дефект]