# Уведомление о готовности переводов (и не только), чтобы модератор поставил метку [статус-завершено]

Tags: поддержка, локализация, мета, метка-модератора

Когда вопрос с метками [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) решён (обычно это значит, что перевод достиг сайта и должен быть виден всем пользователям) хотелось бы видеть на вопросе метку [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

Как можно достучаться до модератора, чтобы он поставил эту метку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будучи обычным пользователем (как давно это было, ох) я стал использовать тревоги "требуется вмешательство модератора" на вопросах с метками [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), когда обозначенная проблема была решена. Т.е. когда перевод обновлён в системе переводов (Transifex/Traducir) и когда он уже подхватился текущей сборкой сайта и его может проверить любой (с учётом возможного доступа к той или иной переводимой сущности) участник. Мне кажется, что этот способ довольно хорошо себя зарекомендовал.

Поэтому предлагаю его использовать и всем остальным. Если вы видите, что вопросу не помешала бы красная метка модератора, смело ставьте тревогу "требуется внимание модератора" и описывайте вкратце суть. Для переводов, которые очевидно легко проверить, достаточно писать что-то вроде "+статус-завершено". Этого должно хватить для заполнения минимальной длины комментария в тревоге. Если для наблюдения перевода в живую (подтверждения того, что он подхватился сайтом) требуется пройти по цепочке страниц, то можно попробовать дать итоговую ссылку на страницу, это упростит работу по проверке. Некоторые ссылки, которые содержат id пользователя можно заменять на `current`, тогда подхватится вариант с текущим авторизованным пользователем (к сожалению, это не всегда работает, но достаточно часто).

Почему это лучше обычного комментария под вопросом или ответом? Уведомление на комментарий могут получить только те участники, которые отметились в сообщении так или иначе (являются автором, вносили правки, комментировали...). Если модератора (участника, который может поставить красную метку) среди них нет, то комментарий может остаться незамеченным и т.о. будет почти бесполезен. Тревоги же доступны для наблюдения всем модераторам, обработать (поставить метку) может любой из них.

Тревогой "требуется внимание модератора" (особенно на Мете) вы никак не навредите автору сообщения, когда просто уведомляете о необходимости добавить метку. Даже если модератор признает тревогу полезной, никаких санкций автоматика не применяет. Поэтому не надо бояться ставить такие тревоги как на своих собственных сообщениях, так и на сообщениях других участников.