# Модераторские метки - не [метки-для-модераторов]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, метка-модератора

На [странице меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) показана "легенда", там показано, что метки, которые могут ставить только модераторы, выделяются красным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Они названы "метка-для-модераторов", в [оригинале](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) - "moderator-only-tag":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С моей точки зрения, перевод не очень удачный, т.к. сами по себе эти метки не только для модераторов (предназначены для модераторов), а для всех - сигнализируют ***всем*** о модераторском решении по вопросу.

Т.е. есть смысловая разница между тем, **для кого** предназначены метки, и **у кого есть права** их ставить.

Возможно стоит заменить на какой-то другой перевод, например:

- модераторская-метка
- метка-модератора

---

**UPD.** Почему вообще у меня возник вопрос по поводу правки этого перевода:

К [одному из вопросов на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12634/1365) добавлена соответствующая метка [метка-для-модераторов](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2) (вообще на нее попал из [очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/983)), мне она показалась полезной, но по формулировке - корявой, потом покопавшись нашел, что эта формулировка есть на странице метаметок. Я решил, что сначала нужно определиться с переводом, потом менять метку.

Comment: Лично мне как-то очевидно, что раз метки видны всем - предлог "для" относится исключительно к возможности их ставить.

Comment: Так-то да, но то же самое тогда можно сказать на любой спорный/корявый перевод, и никакие переводы не исправлять (очевидно же, что имелось в виду).

Comment: Перевод тут полностью соответствует как оригиналу, так и традициям именования подобных объектов.

Comment: Не совсем. moderator-only-tags примерно равно "метки только модераторов" (скорее кому принадлежат метки, а не для чего/кого предназначены)

Comment: У предлога "для" в русском языке есть и такое значение тоже: *"**обозначает субъект, на который направлено какое-либо действие** или который является адресатом чего-либо либо воспринимает что-то"*. В данном случае на метку направлены действия модераторов, всё верно.

Comment: `"обозначает субъект, на который направлено какое-либо действие или который является адресатом чего-либо либо воспринимает что-то"` - т.е. буквально адресатом действия тут становятся модераторы. Не на метку направлены действия модераторов, а "действия" меток направлены на модераторов.

Comment: Кажется, у вас какое-то странное понимание слова **субьект**

Comment: Я понимаю, что такое субъект. Но по ощущению справа от "для" идет как раз объект, на который направлено что-то. В приведенном вами тексте такое впечатление, что объект/субъект перепутаны. Поэтому я и пишу в своем комментарии "адресат", а не субъект.

Comment: Текущий перевод и правда не отражает разницу между "для кого" и "у кого есть права". Но предложенные переводы не лучше. И если выбирать между всеми переводами, то я бы выбрал текущий

Comment: Кажется, из трех озвученных вариантов лучше всего передает смысл вариант "Метка модератора"

Answer (score 7):

Я за вариант `[метка-модератора]` потому что:

- Максимально локанично и нет проблем с "для"
- Модератор в единственном числе как и в оригинале

Answer (score 1):

Изменить перевод не сложно. Вопрос в другом - есть ли в этом реальная необходимость?

Можно ли использовать красные метки неправильно из-за текущего названия? Учитывая, что добавлять/убирать эти метки могут только модераторы, т.е. люди знакомые с системой *очень* хорошо, вряд ли это можно считать вероятным.

Также стоит учесть, что при наведении на эту "метку" появляется описание, которое уточняет суть (если кому-то она не понятна из названия):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Альтернативно могу предположить ещё желание сделать названия более унифицированными, например:

`[модераторская-метка]` `[обязательная-метка]` `[обычная-метка]`

Но это уже выходит за границы текущего предложения.

Comment: Дополнил в вопросе, почему вообще заинтересовался этой формулировкой.

Comment: *Вопрос в другом - есть ли в этом реальная необходимость?* Да, конечно. Это метка не ДЛЯ модератора, а ОТ модератора. Но для ВСЕХ.

Comment: Есть ли в этом реальная необходимость? - Как по мне нет, ибо все знают что это за метки и есть подсказка и самое главное всё равно обычные смертные не могут ими пользоваться. Тем более "метка для модераторов" я всё это время воспринимал как "метка предназначенная для использования только модераторами". Но видимо у людей это вызывает вопросы, потому может быть для улучшения стоит это сделать. Какое бы не было окончательное решение, единственное что я поменял бы 100% - это множественное число на единственное число

Comment: @Akina а как правильно: "приложение на андроид", "для" или "под"? Мне кажется, ответ в том, что "велик и могуч русский язык". Но можно попробовать и на rusSE разузнать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ *а как правильно* - а это зависит от контекста. ИМХО: Написано - "для" (или "под"). Выполняется - "на" (или "под"). В обоих случаях "под" - устоявшийся слэнговый вариант.

Comment: Тут даже не столько контекст, сколько "пропущенное" слово, когда ссылаемся на имя собственное. Если подразумевается платформа, то *для / под*, если операционная система, то *на / под*. Согласен, что **под** довольно универсален и устоялся.