# Требуется перевод страницы "Нормы поведения"

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, нормы-поведения

Сегодня, 31 мая 23-о года страница ["Нормы поведения"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) была обновлена, об этом были извещены пользователи Stack Overflow (английского). Практически вся страница требует перевода, поэтому я решил собрать строки которые требуют перевод в этом вопросе.

- [Our mission is to build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, and to foster collaboration within a safe and welcoming community rooted in kindness, cooperation and mutual respect.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19481)
- [Our expectations for users](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19487)
- [We have outlined below some expectations that are generally true across the network; some sites may have stricter requirements or use different policies for questions/answers/comments. Please adhere to individual site policies where they differ from these expectations.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19488)
- [Engaging with users](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19433)
- [No matter where you engage on the network with your peers, we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect. Remember, we’re all here to learn, and sometimes while learning, people make mistakes. While comments and other actions may not be meant to be harmful, they can still inadvertently end up causing harm. If you encounter something that you believe is harmful, please flag it for moderator attention, and our moderators will assess the situation.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19478)
- [Most people visit the Stack Exchange network to get answers to their questions. For the Community to be able to properly answer your question, there is a minimum quality standard that applies to all new questions. Read more on how to ask a good question.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19499)
- [The knowledge sharing of the Community is the platform's foundation. To ensure the highest quality repository of information, we have adopted quality standards that apply to all answers on our network. Read more on how to write a good answer.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19456)
- [Our voting system is central to how Stack Exchange works. Votes are how the Community signals great content and rewards its members for their contributions. Improperly cast votes undermine the integrity of the platform. Read more on how users are expected to use the voting system. Please see the Unacceptable Behavior section below to find out more about improper voting patterns.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19463)
- [Curating content](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19450)
- [Content on the network is refined through the hard work of community members, and is a vital step in our model. Community members curate content through reviews and edits to keep questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. Read more on how the community curates content.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19441)
- [Commenting](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19491)
- [Comments are generally used in order to request clarification, leave constructive criticism, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post. They're largely regarded as potentially temporary and liberally deleted when no longer needed. Read more on the purpose of comments and their guidelines.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19492)
- [We have outlined key forms of unacceptable behavior across the entire platform:](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19462)
- [Abusive behavior](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19506)
- [We do not allow harassment nor any content that promotes, encourages, glorifies, or threatens acts of violence. We also do not allow causing or contributing to an atmosphere that excludes or marginalizes. Curation activities such as voting (upvotes, downvotes, voting to close, etc) are typically not abusive behaviors. Read more in our Abusive Behavior policy.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19469)
- [Sensitive content and imagery](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19418)
- [We do not allow any content that promotes, encourages, provides instruction for, or glorifies suicidal or self-injurious behaviors. We also do not allow content that promotes, encourages, provides instruction for, or glorifies harm or cruelty. Read more about our Sensitive Content and Imagery policy. If you or someone else is in need of help, please read more on how we treat situations where users are in crisis.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19511)
- [Harmful political content](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19416)
- [We do not allow political content that encourages harm to others or that supports, celebrates, or furthers the cause of violent actors and hate organizations. We may, in some places, allow pointed or harsh criticism of political figures, their policies, and governments (including satirical statements) as long as they do not otherwise violate this Code of Conduct. Read more in our Harmful Political Content policy.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19439)
- [Misleading information](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19480)
- [We do not allow any content that promotes false, harmful, or misleading information that carries the risk of harm to a person or group of people. We also do not allow content that promotes false or misleading information for the purpose of promoting the interests of a political party, government, or ideology. Read more in our Misleading information policy.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19508)
- [Disruptive use of tooling](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19444)
- [We do not allow any use of privileges in a targeted and disruptive manner that causes harm to the community or compromises the integrity of the content. Read more about our Disruptive Use policy.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19466)
- [Inauthentic Usage](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19454)
- [We do not allow any use of the system that violates our Acceptable Use policy or directly causes unnecessary and unwanted disruption and/or harm to users and/or the network. Read more about our Inauthentic Usage policy.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19422)
- [Every person contributes to building a collaborative, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others, you can flag the harmful content. Moderators review flags regularly, and users who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team, including, but not limited to, account suspensions.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19421)
- [All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators. If you’re not satisfied with a moderator decision, you are welcome to appeal it by contacting us directly. We review each report individually and will respond as quickly as we can.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10187) *(На эту строку уже предложен перевод)*
- [Site Policies](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19458)
- [This Code of Conduct is meant to work alongside individual site policies. Sites and Chatrooms may choose more restrictive policies for their content than what is allowed here, particularly around what is on-topic or off-topic.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19494)
- [Usernames and profiles](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19447)
- [While we encourage users to express themselves in their profiles, all user profiles in their entirety are subject to the Code of Conduct and all policies outlined or incorporated therein.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19455)

Answer (score 3):

Добавил предложения переводов некоторых строк:

- *Our mission is to build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, and to foster collaboration within a safe and welcoming community rooted in kindness, cooperation and mutual respect.* - [Наша миссия - это создать библиотеки высококачественных вопросов и ответов, и содействовать сотрудничеству вместе с безопасным и гостеприимным сообществом, истоки которого в доброте, кооперировании и во взаимном уважении.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19481)
- *Our expectations for users* - [Наши ожидания от участников](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19487)
- *We have outlined below some expectations that are generally true across the network; some sites may have stricter requirements or use different policies for questions/answers/comments. Please adhere to individual site policies where they differ from these expectations.* - [Снизу, мы отметили некоторые ожидания, которые в основном верны по всей сети; Некоторые сайты имеют более строгие требования или используют другие правила для вопросов/ответов/комментариев. Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь индивидуальных политик сайта, которые отличаются от этих ожиданий.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19488)
- *Engaging with users* - [Взаимодействие с участниками](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19433)
- *No matter where you engage on the network with your peers, we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect. Remember, we’re all here to learn, and sometimes while learning, people make mistakes. While comments and other actions may not be meant to be harmful, they can still inadvertently end up causing harm. If you encounter something that you believe is harmful, please flag it for moderator attention, and our moderators will assess the situation.* - [Не важно как вы взаимодействуете в сети с вашими коллегами, мы ожидаем от всех участников одинакового относиться к друг другу, с добротой и уважением. Помните, мы все здесь для того, чтобы учиться и иногда во время обучения, люди совершают ошибки. В то время как комментарии и другие действия могут не предполагаться как вредные, они всё равно могут непреднамеренно нанести вред. Если вы встречаетесь с чем-то, что по вашему мнению вредно, пожалуйста, отметьте это тревогой для того, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора и наши модераторы оценят ситуацию.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19478)
- *Most people visit the Stack Exchange network to get answers to their questions. For the Community to be able to properly answer your question, there is a minimum quality standard that applies to all new questions. Read more on how to ask a good question.* - [Большинство людей посещает сеть Stack Exchange, чтобы получить ответы на их вопросы. Чтобы сообщество было способно должным образом ответить на ваш вопрос, существуют минимальные стандарты качества, которые применяются ко всем новым вопросам. Прочитайте больше о том, как задать хороший вопрос.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19499)
- *The knowledge sharing of the Community is the platform's foundation. To ensure the highest quality repository of information, we have adopted quality standards that apply to all answers on our network. Read more on how to write a good answer.* - [Обмен знаниями в сообществе - это основа платформы. Чтобы убедиться в наивысшем качестве репозитория информации, мы приняли стандарты качества на все ответы в нашей сети. Прочитайте больше о том, как написать хороший ответ.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19456)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12634/%d0%a3%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: @EzioMercer спасибо, но ещё не все переводы готовы.